# 3D TikZ lines on the perimeter of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, 3d

I'm just learning TikZ, I've done a few 2D images and I wanted to make a 3D wire frame of the Hubble telescope.  The body of the telescope is basically a pair of tubes, the front one slightly narrower than the other.  I had thought to draw a series of circles and then put lines along them to create a cylinder.

The problem is, my lines don't fall on the perimeter of the circles.  I the circle command to draw the circles on the `(y,z)` plane while `x` varies along the length of the telescope.  I had thought to calculate end points for the lines use the equations `y = radius * cos(\theta)` and `z = radius * sin(\theta)` but the lines turn out to be slightly off the surface of the cylinder.  I've tried a bunch of different things.  One really strange thing ( to me) is that if I specify the radius in centimetres for the line calculations the lines are *Way* off the cylinder.  Even though the radius is specified in `cm` for the circles.

```
\tikzset{
    MyPersp/.style={scale=1.8,x={(-0.8cm,-0.4cm)},y={(0.8cm,-0.4cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}}
}

\newcommand{\hubble}[0] {%
    \foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,1.0} {
        \draw[very thick] (\x,0,0) circle (0.75cm);
    }
    \draw[very thick] (1.25,0,0) circle ({1.25cm / 2});
    \foreach \x in {1.5,1.75,...,2.25} {
        \draw[very thick] (\x,0,0) circle (0.5cm);
    }

    \foreach \r/\x/\xx in {0.75/0/1,0.5/1.5/2.25}{
        \foreach \theta in {0,30,...,360}{
            \def\y{{\r*cos(\theta)}}
            \def\z{{\r*sin(\theta)}}
            \draw[very thick](\x,\y,\z) -- (\xx,\y,\z);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[MyPersp]

\hubble

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Resulting Image]

Comment: Oh, and as to why the deviations occur: `TikZ` will assume that you want to draw in the xy-plane if You use `circle`. For using the xz-plane or the yz-plane, have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/drawing-a-circle-on-a-non-xy-plane-with-tikz) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63118/specifying-the-transformation-matrix-tikz-uses-manually/63121#63121).

Comment: Ah I did not know that, makes sense why they don't match up then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the solution that requires the minimal amount of modification to your original code:

```
\newcommand{\hubble}[0] {%
    \foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,1} {
       \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\x]
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (0.75cm);
       \end{scope}
    }
    %\draw[very thick] (1.25,0,0) circle ({1.25cm / 2});
    \foreach \x in {1.5,1.75,...,2.25} {
          \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\x]
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
       \end{scope}
    }

    \foreach \r/\x/\xx in {0.75/0/1,0.5/1.5/2.25}{
        \foreach \theta in {0,30,...,360}{
            \def\y{{\r*cos(\theta)}}
            \def\z{{\r*sin(\theta)}}
            \draw[very thick](\x,\y,\z) -- (\xx,\y,\z);
        }
    }

}
```

A you can see, the trick is to specify as the 'active canvas' the yz plane each time you draw a circle at a new `x` coordinate. Now the radius and the center of the circle can be specified in the usual `2d` fashion.

You will need to load the the `3d` TikZ library to make it work (insert the line `\usetikzlibrary{3d}` in the preamble, naturally after loading the TikZ package).

The lines will remain consistently on the circles even if you change the perspective parameters.

Answer (score 7):

How about this: I make the circles grow along the z-axis. The small circles are of radius 1, the bid ones of radius 2, the z-separation of the circles is 0.6 units. From polar coordinates we know that `x=r cos(phi)` and `y=r sin(phi)`. I don't know if you want this to be customizable, but this could be easily added.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\zdeg}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{cos(\zdeg)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{sin(\zdeg)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(\zx*1cm,\zy*1cm)}]
    \foreach \z in {0,...,5}
    {   \draw (0,0,\z*0.6) circle (1);
        \draw (0,0,\z*0.6+3) circle (2);
    }
    \foreach \deg in {1,...,18}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\xval}{cos(20*\deg)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yval}{sin(20*\deg)}
        \draw (\xval,\yval,0) -- (\xval,\yval,3);
        \draw (2*\xval,2*\yval,3) -- (2*\xval,2*\yval,6);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, that works for what I want.  I will want it to be customizable but I was trying to get something that looked like what I wanted first.