# Documentation of the tikz 3d library

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Where can I find the documentation of the tikz 3d library? There seems to be no such section in the manual and google didn't help me in this case.

Comment: And whay you mean with tikz3d library? I was having no problem finding answers about 3D in [PGF/TikZ manual](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: The library you can load via `\usetikzlibrary{3d}`. If I search the `pdf` of the manual I only get things about 3d charts. Could you point me to the correct pages in the manual?

Comment: @student, the documentation is now in the manual, Chapter 40 page 564 as of september 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those still stumbling here, this question is very old and there is now documentation for the `3d` library.
As of September 2023 it can be found in Part V, Chapter 40, page 564 of the TikZ/PGF manual.

Answer (score 24):

I've found several related answers:

- [TikZ: How to draw an isometric drawing in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59406/tikz-how-to-draw-an-isometric-drawing-in-tikz/59410#59410)
- [Specifying the transformation matrix TikZ uses manually?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63118/specifying-the-transformation-matrix-tikz-uses-manually)

So, I've went and look into the sources of Ti*k*Z 3D library, here it is (all of it):

```
% Copyright 2006 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/generic/pgf/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\ProvidesFileRCS[v\pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary3d.code.tex,v 1.1 2008/01/09 17:57:15 tantau Exp $

% New coordinate systems:
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{xyz cylindrical}
{%
  \pgfset{/tikz/cs/.cd,angle=0,radius=0,z=0,#1}%
  \pgfpointcylindrical{\tikz@cs@angle}{\tikz@cs@radius}{\tikz@cs@z}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{xyz spherical}
{%
  \pgfset{/tikz/cs/.cd,angle=0,radius=0,latitude=0,longitude=0,#1}%
  \pgfpointspherical{\tikz@cs@angle}{\tikz@cs@latitude}{\tikz@cs@radius}%
}

\pgfset{/tikz/cs/longitude/.store in=\tikz@cs@angle}
\pgfset{/tikz/cs/latitude/.store in=\tikz@cs@latitude}

% Options for transforming into a plane:
\tikzoption{plane origin}{\def\tikz@plane@origin{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1}}
\tikzoption{plane x}{\def\tikz@plane@x{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1}}
\tikzoption{plane y}{\def\tikz@plane@y{\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1}}

\let\tikz@plane@origin=\pgfpointorigin
\def\tikz@plain@x{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}
\def\tikz@plain@y{\pgfpointxy{0}{1}}

\tikzoption{canvas is plane}[]{
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}{%
  \tikz@addtransform{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}}%
}
\tikzoption{canvas is yx plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\tikzoption{canvas is xz plane at y}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{#1}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{#1}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{#1}{1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\tikzoption{canvas is zx plane at y}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{#1}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{0}{#1}{1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{1}{#1}{0}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\tikzoption{canvas is yz plane at x}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{0}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{1}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{0}{1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\tikzoption{canvas is zy plane at x}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{0}{0}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{0}{1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{#1}{1}{0}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}

% Transformation code
\def\tikz@canvas@is@plane{
  \pgf@process{\tikz@plane@x}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@process{\tikz@plane@y}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
  \pgf@process{\tikz@plane@origin}%
  \edef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\tikz@addtransform{%
      \noexpand\pgftransformtriangle
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}}
      {\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@xb}{\the\pgf@yb}}
      \noexpand\pgftransformscale{0.035146}%
      \noexpand\pgfsetxvec{\noexpand\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}%
      \noexpand\pgfsetyvec{\noexpand\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}%
      \noexpand\pgfsetzvec{\noexpand\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
    }}%
  \pgf@marshal%
}

\endinput
```

Looks simple but, not yet documented. Summarizing, it introduces some new coordinates systems:

- `xyz cylindrical` with `angle`, `radius` and `height` as parameters.
- `xyz spherical` with `angle`, `latitude` and `radius` as an option introduces `longtitude` as an `angle` define.

And some new TikZ options to set, which plane to draw:

```
plane origin
plane x
plane y
canvas is plane
canvas is xy plane at z
canvas is yx plane at z
canvas is xz plane at y
canvas is zx plane at y
canvas is yz plane at x
canvas is zy plane at x
```

That's all.