# Draw lower (southern) hemisphere and great semicircle with "mathematician's" axes orientation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

With `tikz` and `tikz-3dplot` I want to draw:

- the unit lower (i.e., southern) hemisphere; and on that
- two great semicircles through the south pole, i.e., point $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, -1)$, the first joining the points $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, 0)$ and the second joining the points $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}, 0)$; and
- points at the ends of each of those great semicircles (in my code, shown below, I could use `dot`, perhaps?)

[Meta question: how does one enter LaTeX code here??]

Moreover, I want the drawing to show the x-, y-, z-axes with the orientation and position that mathematicians so often use for sketches on paper or on a blackboard, namely: z-axis pointing straight up; y-axis pointing directly to the right, that is on the 2D paper, towards due east); and x-axis "outward" but, as drawn on paper, pointing to the southwest — as shown in this image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space:

[image: "mathematician's" 3D axes drawing]

In particular, I do *not* want the southest-pointing" x-axis to be unduly foreshortened.

**Edit: rough version of what I want**

The following was drawn with *Mathematica*, but for consistency with my LaTeX document and other graphics there, I need a version done in Ti*k*Z.

The positive z-axis in this version exends *much* further north than I actually want!

[image: Great semicircle on southern hemisphere.]

Here's my incomplete start:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{calc}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110} % theta, phi

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
   dot/.default = 4pt,  % size of the circle diameter
  ]

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1.25*\radius,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$X$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.25*\radius,0) node[anchor=north west]{$Y$};
  \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.25*\radius) node[anchor=south]{$Z$};

  \tdplotdrawarc[thick,gray!90] {(O)}{\radius}{0}{360}{}{};% equator
  % shaded southern hemisphere:
  \shade[ball color=gray!20!white,opacity=0.3] (1cm,0) arc (0:180:1cm and 5mm) arc (-180:0:1cm and 1cm);

  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{270}{90}; % semicircle for lower hemishphere
  \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords,thick,color=gray!90] {(O)}{\radius}{0}{180}{}{};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Southern hemisphere - crude attempt.]

**Question**: How accomplish this?

Evidently it would suffice if I could find out how to draw one of those great semicircles and the points on the equator at its ends.

My difficulty is in 3d visualization, i.e., "seeing" how to rotate everything, first to get the axes orientation right, second to move things into position to draw each great semicircle.

Comment: To your "meta question": MathJax is (intentionally) disabled on this site.

Comment: @TeXnician: drat!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>Like this?</s> Obviously not! See below for a newer version!

[image]

The Tikz library `3d` is very helpful here. You can use styles as `canvas is xy plane at z=0` to start drawing on a certain plane, and `rotate around z=45` to rotate the entire coordinate system about `z` (or any other axis). See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75948/74459) for the available options.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{1}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110} % theta, phi

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords,
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
    dot/.default = 4pt,  % size of the circle diameter
]

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

    % equator
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,thick,gray!90] (0,0) circle (\radius);

    % shaded southern hemisphere:
    \shade[ball color=gray!20!white,opacity=0.3] (1cm,0) arc (0:180:1cm and 5mm) arc (-180:0:1cm and 1cm);

    % two semicircles
    \foreach \ang in {-45,45}{
        \draw[rotate around z=\ang,canvas is xz plane at y=0,thick,color=gray!90] (0,0) ++(0:\radius) arc (0:-180:\radius);
        \path[rotate around z=\ang] (1,0,0) node[dot]{} (-1,0,0) node[dot]{};
    }

    % axes
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1.25*\radius,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$X$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.25*\radius,0) node[anchor=north west]{$Y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.25*\radius) node[anchor=south]{$Z$};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

**Edit  <sub><sup>You will have to scroll further down for another edit.</sup></sub>** 
It's still a bit unclear for me what your asking, but that is probably due to me not understanding properly, and *not* due to you not explaining properly :) I made a version that is a bit more like the Mathematica example you provided.

To achieve it I adjusted the shading to make the `y radius` dependent of the current elevation angle `\el`. I also added another shading area that strengthens the '3D feel' of the hemisphere by overlaying part of the former shading (see the image, I can't explain this very well).

[image]

I added a `view={<azimuth>}{<elevation>}` key that sets the view angle. The `<azimuth>` angle is measured w.r.t. the negative y axis in the xy plane, and the `<elevation>` angle is measured w.r.t. the horizontal xy plane, so if both angles are zero, z points up and x points right. I don't know how Mathematica sets its 3D viewing point, but the Matlab [`view`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) command works as above. The following animation shows in what order the rotations are executed (I changed the shading to a fill for this animation due to the upload limit on image size):

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}

% view={<azimuth>,<elevation>} key
\tikzset{
    view/.code args={#1,#2}{%
        % Set elevation and azimuth angles
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@az{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@el{#2}
        % Calculate projections of rotation matrix
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@x{cos(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@y{-sin(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@x{sin(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@y{cos(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@x{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@y{cos(\view@el)}
        % Set base vectors
        \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{\xvec@x cm}{\xvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{\yvec@x cm}{\yvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{\zvec@x cm}{\zvec@y cm}}
    },
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={
        circle,
        fill,
        minimum size=#1,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt
    },
    dot/.default = 4pt,
    hemisphere/.style={
        ball color=gray!20!white,
        fill=none,
        opacity=0.3,
    },
    equator/.style={
        thick,
        gray!90,
    },
    axis/.style={
        thick,
        -stealth,
        black!60,
        every node/.style={
            text=black,
            at={([turn]1mm,0mm)}
        },
    },
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\el{10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        view={105,\el}, % {<azimuth>}{<elevation>}
    ]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

        % shaded southern hemisphere: (on bottom)
        \fill[
            hemisphere,
            delta angle=180,
            x radius=\radius cm
        ] (\radius cm,0)
            \ifnum\el=0
                -- ++(-2*\radius,0,0)
            \else
                arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0]
            \fi
            arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];

        % another hemisphere (on top)
        \fill[
            hemisphere,
            delta angle=180,
            x radius=\radius cm,
        ] (\radius cm,0)
            arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
            arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];

        % equator
        \draw[equator,canvas is xy plane at z=0] (O) circle (\radius);

        % two semicircles
        \foreach \ang in {-45,45}{
            \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\ang]
                \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,thick,color=gray!90] (0,0) ++(0:\radius) arc (0:-180:\radius);
                \node[dot] at (\radius,0,0) {};
                \node[dot] at (-\radius,0,0) {};
            \end{scope}
        }

        % axes
        \begin{scope}[scale=1.1*\radius]
            \draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1,0,0  ) node {$X$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0,-1, 0) -- (0,1,0  ) node {$Y$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0, 0,-1) -- (0,0,0.5) node {$Z$};
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

MWE Animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}

% view={<azimuth>,<elevation>} key
\tikzset{
    view/.code args={#1,#2}{%
        % Set elevation and azimuth angles
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@az{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@el{#2}
        % Calculate projections of rotation matrix
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@x{cos(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@y{-sin(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@x{sin(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@y{cos(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@x{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@y{cos(\view@el)}
        % Set base vectors
        \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{\xvec@x cm}{\xvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{\yvec@x cm}{\yvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{\zvec@x cm}{\zvec@y cm}}
    },
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={
        circle,
        fill,
        minimum size=#1,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt
    },
    dot/.default = 4pt,
    hemisphere/.style={
        gray,
        fill opacity=0.3,
    },
    equator/.style={
        thick,
        gray!90,
    },
    axis/.style={
        thick,
        -stealth,
        black!60,
        every node/.style={
            text=black,
            at={([turn]1mm,0mm)}
        },
    },
}

\newcommand{\drawSouthernHemisphere}{
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \clip (-1.5*\radius cm, -1.25*\radius cm) rectangle (1.5*\radius cm, 1*\radius cm);

    \path (5cm,4cm) node[align=left,left] {azimuth: \\ elevation:} node[align=right,right,text width=1cm] {\az$ ^\circ $\\ \el$ ^\circ $};
    % shaded southern hemisphere: (on bottom)
    \fill[
        hemisphere,
        delta angle=180,
        x radius=\radius cm
    ] (\radius cm,0)
        \ifnum\el=0
            -- ++(-2*\radius cm,0)
        \else
            arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0]
        \fi
        arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];
    % another hemisphere (on top)
    \fill[
        hemisphere,
        delta angle=180,
        x radius=\radius cm,
    ] (\radius cm,0)
        \ifnum\el=0
            -- ++(-2*\radius cm,0)
        \else
            arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
        \fi
        arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];
    % equator
    \ifnum\el=0
        \draw[equator] (-\radius cm,0) -- (\radius cm,0);
    \else
        \draw[equator,canvas is xy plane at z=0] (O) circle (\radius);
    \fi
    % two semicircles
    \foreach \ang in {-45,45}{
        \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\ang]
            \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,thick,color=gray!90] (0,0) ++(0:\radius) arc (0:-180:\radius);
            \node[dot] at (\radius,0,0) {};
            \node[dot] at (-\radius,0,0) {};
        \end{scope}
    }
    % axes
    \begin{scope}[scale=1.1*\radius]
        \draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1,0,0  ) node {$X$};
        \draw[axis] ( 0,-1, 0) -- (0,1,0  ) node {$Y$};
        \draw[axis] ( 0, 0,-1) -- (0,0,0.5) node {$Z$};
    \end{scope}
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{5}

\begin{document}
\foreach \az in {0,5,...,100}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\el{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[view={\az,\el}]% {<azimuth>}{<elevation>}
        \drawSouthernHemisphere
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \el in {0,2,...,10,10,10,8,...,2}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\az{105}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[view={\az,\el}]% {<azimuth>}{<elevation>}
        \drawSouthernHemisphere
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \az in {105,100,...,0,0,0}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\el{0}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[view={\az,\el}]% {<azimuth>}{<elevation>}
        \drawSouthernHemisphere
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**
I think what you want is a *cabinet* projection (which I believe is not really an *orthographic* projection, but an *oblique* projection, but I also found some writings stating that *oblique* is a subset of *orthographic*). The solution presented above is also orthographic, and definitely *not* perspective (see [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/74459) for a perspective view).

3D projections can be set with Ti*k*z fairly easy, by setting the base vectors of the coordinate system as projected on the paper. For example, for a view from the positive y axis, those base vectors are `x=[-1;0]`, `y=[0 0]`, and `z=[0;1]`. The `view` key mentioned above sets the base vectors according to its input angles. For the *cabinet* projection, we would want the following base vectors:

- `z=[0;1]` To point the `z` vector straight up on the paper;
- `y=[1;0]` To point the `y` vector to the right on the paper;
- `x=[-0.3536;-0.3536]` To point to the below-left on the paper. These values are `1/2*cos(225)` and `1/2*sin(225)` which happen to be the same for 225 degrees (big surprise `:)` ).

The problem with these base vectors for a *cabinet* projection are that the projection of a perfect sphere on the paper, which is expected to be a perfect circle from *any* view, now becomes an ellipse. To demonstrate this I drew a number of circles which represent a sphere (this way I can let Ti*k*z do the mapping in the coordinate system).

The left image is with the orthographic coordinate system, set with `view={105,25}`, the middle is set with the key `cabinet projection` which sets the base vectors as listed above, and the right one is drawn in a *cavalier* projection (set with `cavalier projection` key), which is similar to the *cabinet* projection, only with a longer x base vector, so the sphere is even more ellipsoid. See also the house shapes in the same projections.

[image]

I actually also tried to come up with a poor man solution to the above, namely drawing the half-sphere in *orthographic* projection with a slight additional rotation about z, with the axes drawn in the *cabinet* projection. This comes out as:

[image]

For completeness I also added the 'real' projection axes in red, to highlight the difference:

[image]

The above images were drawn with the following code. I made a `\drawSphereWithAxes` and a `\drawHouseWithAxes` command just for repeating these easily, but they are obviously not needed for your solution so you can simply throw them out.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}

% view={<azimuth>,<elevation>} key
\tikzset{
    view/.code args={#1,#2}{%
        % Set elevation and azimuth angles
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@az{#1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\view@el{#2}
        % Calculate projections of rotation matrix
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@x{cos(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\xvec@y{-sin(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@x{sin(\view@az)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\yvec@y{cos(\view@az)*sin(\view@el)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@x{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\zvec@y{cos(\view@el)}
        % Set base vectors
        \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{\xvec@x cm}{\xvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{\yvec@x cm}{\yvec@y cm}}
        \pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{\zvec@x cm}{\zvec@y cm}}
    },
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    dot/.style={
        circle,
        fill,
        minimum size=#1,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt
    },
    dot/.default = 4pt,
    hemisphere/.style={
        ball color=gray!20!white,
        fill=none,
        opacity=0.3,
    },
    equator/.style={
        thick,
        gray!90,
    },
    axis/.style={
        thick,
        -stealth,
        black!60,
        every node/.style={
            text=black,
            at={([turn]1mm,0mm)}
        },
    },
    cabinet projection/.style={
        x={({0.5*cos(225)*10mm},{0.5*sin(225)*10mm})},
        y={(10mm,0mm)},
        z={(0mm,10mm)},
    },
    cavalier projection/.style={
        x={({cos(225)*10mm},{sin(225)*10mm})},
        y={(10mm,0mm)},
        z={(0mm,10mm)},
    },
}

\newcommand\drawSphereWithAxes{
    \foreach \ang [evaluate=\ang as \height using {\radius*cos(\ang)}] in {0,5,...,179}{
        \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\ang]
            \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle (\radius);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\height]
            \draw[opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle ({\radius*sin(\ang)});
        \end{scope}
    }
    \begin{scope}[scale=\radius]
        \begin{scope}[scale=1.3]
            \draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1,0,0) node {$X$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0,-1, 0) -- (0,1,0) node {$Y$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0, 0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node {$Z$};
        \end{scope}
        \path foreach \crossing in {{(-1,0,0)},{(1,0,0)},{(0,-1,0)},{(0,1,0)},{(0,0,-1)},{(0,0,1)}}{ \crossing node[dot]{}};
    \end{scope}
}
\newcommand\drawHouseWithAxes{
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
        \draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0  ) -- (1,0,0  ) node {$X$};
        \draw[axis] ( 0,-1, 0  ) -- (0,1,0  ) node {$Y$};
        \draw[axis] ( 0, 0,-0.5) -- (0,0,1.5) node {$Z$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.1,line join=round,shift={(-1,-1,0)}]
        \filldraw (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (0,2,0) -- (0,2,1) -- (0,1,2) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,0,0) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (0,2,1) -- (0,1,2) -- (2,1,2) -- (2,2,1) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (0,0,1) -- (0,1,2) -- (2,1,2) -- (2,0,1) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (2,0,1) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (0,2,0) -- (0,2,1) -- (2,2,1) -- (2,2,0) -- cycle;
        \filldraw (2,2,0) -- (2,2,1) -- (2,1,2) -- (2,0,1) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\el{10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[cabinet projection]

        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

        \begin{scope}[view={90,\el},rotate around z=-10]

            % shaded southern hemisphere: (on bottom)
            \fill[
                hemisphere,
                delta angle=180,
                x radius=\radius cm
            ] (\radius cm,0)
                arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0]
                arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];

            % another hemisphere (on top)
            \fill[
                hemisphere,
                delta angle=180,
                x radius=\radius cm,
            ] (\radius cm,0)
                arc [y radius={\radius*sin(\el)*1cm},start angle=0,delta angle=-180]
                arc [y radius=\radius cm,start angle=-180];

            % equator
            \draw[equator,canvas is xy plane at z=0] (O) circle (\radius);

            % two semicircles
            \foreach \ang in {-45,45}{
                \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\ang]
                    \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,thick,color=gray!90] (0,0) ++(0:\radius) arc (0:-180:\radius);
                    \node[dot] at (\radius,0,0) {};
                    \node[dot] at (-\radius,0,0) {};
                \end{scope}
            }

            % Real sphere projection axes
            \begin{scope}[scale=1.1*\radius]
                \draw[axis,red,very thick] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1,0,0  ) node {$X'$};
                \draw[axis,red,very thick] ( 0,-1, 0) -- (0,1,0  ) node {$Y'$};
                \draw[axis,red,very thick] ( 0, 0,-1) -- (0,0,0.5) node {$Z'$};
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

        % axes
        \begin{scope}[scale=1.1*\radius]
            \draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1,0,0  ) node {$X$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0,-1, 0) -- (0,1,0  ) node {$Y$};
            \draw[axis] ( 0, 0,-1) -- (0,0,0.5) node {$Z$};
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{2}

        \begin{scope}[view={105,25}]
            \node at (0cm,4cm) {\huge Orthographic};
            \drawSphereWithAxes
            \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6cm)}]
                \drawHouseWithAxes
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[cabinet projection,shift={(7cm,0cm)}]
            \node at (0cm,4cm) {\huge Cabinet};
            \drawSphereWithAxes
            \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6cm)}]
                \drawHouseWithAxes
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[cavalier projection,shift={(14cm,0cm)}]
            \node at (0cm,4cm) {\huge Cavalier};
            \drawSphereWithAxes
            \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6cm)}]
                \drawHouseWithAxes
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! +1 . In case the OP does not like the 3d library, you could just do `\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:180,smooth,samples=60] ({cos(45)*cos(\x)},{sin(45)*cos(\x)}{-sin(\x)});` and the same with `-45` instead of `45`. If you do that in rotated coordinates, you can rotate the hemisphere, of course.

Comment: I dunno, according to his profile he is a mathematician, and I can not see any reason why he has not accepted your nice answer so I am speculating why. ;-) The only other reason may be that he is waiting for the dots at the end.

Comment: @Max: which command(s) draw the dots?

Comment: @murray Inside the `\foreach` the line `\path[rotate around z=\ang] (1,0,0) node[dot]{} (-1,0,0) node[dot]{};` draws a dot on `x=1` and `x=-1` but these coordinates are rotated 45 or -45 degrees w.r.t. the other frame.

Comment: @Max: got it! Now I just have to figure out, in general for Ti*k*Z, when to use `\draw ... node ...` vs. when to use `\node ...`.

Comment: @Max: But I want the x-, y-, z-axes to be in standard "mathematician's" positions, with y-axis pointing due east, and everything else adjusted accordingly.  couldn't figure that out at all simply by fiddling with the theta and phi in `\tdplotsetmaincoords`.

Comment: @murray You don't need `tikz-3dplot` to do that, you simply need to set `x={(-0.707 cm,-0.707 cm)},y={(1cm,0cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)}` in the scope where you want to draw in that sort of 'semi-3D'. There is a line in my MWE that is commented out, but if you remove the `%` it will do as you want. When you use `\node`, Tikz will execute `\path node` so in general there is no difference, but I wanted both nodes to inherit the `rotate around z` option, so I used a single `\path` with two nodes.

Comment: @Max: no, just uncommenting out that line creates equator and great semicircles that no longer lie on the shaded southern hemisphere. See my edit for a rough version of what I want.

Comment: @murray I'm afraid I don't follow. Do you want _only_ the axis drawn in that 'mathematicians's' frame? And the semicircles in the normal frame?

Comment: @murray Does my edit help?

Comment: @Max: Almost exactly what I'm after. The one issue remaining: How make the positive x-axis point due east on the paper (or screen) so that it is "horizontal", yet keep the z-axis vertical and the x-axis pointing southwest (again, with reference to the paper (or screen on which this is drawn)?

Comment: The main *Mathematica* way to set how the entire 3D graphic is viewed is  option `ViewPoint -> {xcoord, ycood, zcoord}` where `xcoord`, `ycood`, `zcoord` are specific Cartesian coordinates of the viewpoint. (There are additional options `ViewCenter`, `ViewAngle`, `ViewVector`, `ViewProjection`, etc.) Yet still the annoying *Mathematica* default is that the y-axis points northeast on the page (as if pointing backwards, away from the viewer); the x-axis points southeast on the page (as if pointing somewhat outwards towards the viewer); and the z-axis does point nearly straight up on the page.

Comment: Everthing should be with reference to the same ("mathematician's") frame. Imagine slicing a thin-walled ball in half to form a half-ball; with a marker mark the 4 points on its equator, then draw great semi-circles connecting pairs of antipodal points on the equation; then on paper or a blackboard draw a picture of the whole thing in a "mathematician's" frame, with positive x-axis pointing due southwest, positive y-axis pointing due east, positive z-axis pointing due north. To effect this requires an orthographic projection rather than a perspective projection.

Comment: @murray I hope my latest edit adds a sufficient solution (and some explanation).

Comment: @Max: The Cabinet projection gets the axes the way mathematicians draw sketches -- and seeing that is a big help -- but it distorts the sphere; on Cabinet-type axes, a mathematician would still draw the sphere so it's completely "spherical"! In any case, I solicit and will welcome reactions to "Questions about my version based on answer by @Max" (as well as any suggestions for improving the figure's appearance itself).

Comment: @murray I don't see how your version is different from my proposed "poor man's solution". Anyway, for your follow-up questions you should ask a new question, and refer back to this one.

Comment: @Max: What about the question of how to draw the axes in Cabinet projection *without* distorting shapes (here, *without* distorting the sphere, i.e., so that a cross-section of the sphere parallel to one of the coordinate planes still appears as a circle?

Comment: @murray I did that by drawing the axes in cabinet projection, and the sphere in orthographic projection? Or do I understand wrongly?

Comment: @murray In my last two images, the sphere is not distorted.

Comment: @Max: noted now! Sorry for not understanding that part of "Edit 2" the first time 'round.

Comment: @murray no problem! I hope you found it to be useful.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Comment: For the record : since v3.1.2 the commands used in the preamble to define azimuth and elevation angles can be replaced by a simple call to the `perspective` library developed by @Max .