# Drawing a cylinder in 3D coordinates

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I want to draw a picture like this.

[image]

But I take on problems in terms of perspective (line 35) and the cylinder.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{rusia}{RGB}{85 85 57}
\definecolor{brightcerulean}{rgb}{0.11, 0.67, 0.84}
\definecolor{brandeisblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.44, 1.0}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\ds\displaystyle
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,intersections,decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple,labelfont=footnotesize,font=footnotesize,hypcap=false,skip=3pt]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% fix wrong implementation of xy canvas
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{86}{50} % pengaturan sudut pandang (persfektif)
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,4,0);
\coordinate (D) at (0,0,2.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,4,1.3);
\coordinate (F) at (5,4,1.75);
\draw[very thin,canvas is xy plane at z=0,darkgray!40] (0,0) grid (5,4);
\draw[ultra thin,gray] (D)--(A)--(B)--(C)--(F);

\begin{scope}[decoration={zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm}]
\shade  (A)--(D) decorate {-- (E)}--(B)--cycle ;
\shade  (B)--(E) decorate {-- (F)}--(C)--cycle ;
\end{scope}

\shade[canvas is yz plane at x=.5,top color=white,bottom color=brandeisblue] (1,0)--(2,0) arc(-90:90:.2)--(1,.4) arc(90:-90:.2);
\shade[canvas is yz plane at x=.5,ball color=Cerulean!50, shading angle=225] (1,.2) circle (.2);

\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (D)--(E);
\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (E)--(F);

\draw[very thin,canvas is yz plane at x=.5,brandeisblue!70] (1,0)--(2,0) (2,.4)--(1,.4) 
(1,.2) circle (.2) (2,0) arc(-90:90:.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this come anywhere close to what you would want to achieve?

[image]

What I did was removing the `tikz-3dplot` package, because it will give you an orthographic projection of 3D space. The first image you provided is not drawn in an orthographic projection, so it is impossible to replicate with `tikz-3dplot`. (See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447388/draw-lower-southern-hemisphere-and-great-semicircle-with-mathematicians-axe/447401#comment1125674_447401) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447991/how-draw-axes-figure-with-tikz-using-mathematicians-axes?noredirect=1&lq=1) question for why that is, explained expertly by [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in the latter.)

Next I set the `x`, `y`, and `z` base vectors manually (I used `\yangle` to define the `y` base vector, and use that macro a few times in drawing the cylinder.).

Finally I only changed your cylinder drawing code, as function of `\yangle`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{rusia}{RGB}{85 85 57}
\definecolor{brightcerulean}{rgb}{0.11, 0.67, 0.84}
\definecolor{brandeisblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.44, 1.0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% fix wrong implementation of xy canvas
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro\yangle{30}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    y={({0.5*cos(\yangle)*1cm},{0.5*sin(\yangle)*1cm})},
    x={(1cm,0cm)},
    z={(0cm,1cm)}
]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,4,0);
\coordinate (D) at (0,0,2.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,4,1.3);
\coordinate (F) at (5,4,1.75);
\draw[very thin,canvas is xy plane at z=0,darkgray!40] (0,0) grid (5,4);
\draw[ultra thin,gray] (D)--(A)--(B)--(C)--(F);

\begin{scope}[decoration={zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm}]
\shade  (A)--(D) decorate {-- (E)}--(B)--cycle ;
\shade  (B)--(E) decorate {-- (F)}--(C)--cycle ;
\end{scope}

\shade[top color=white,bottom color=brandeisblue,shading angle=45] (0.2,1,0.2) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) -- ++(0,1,0) arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm) -- ++(0,-1,0) arc (\yangle-90:\yangle+90:0.2cm);
\shade[ball color=Cerulean!50, shading angle=225] (0.2,1,0.2) circle (0.2cm);

\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (D)--(E);
\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (E)--(F);

\draw[very thin,brandeisblue!70] (0.2,1,0.2) circle (0.2cm) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) -- ++(0,1,0) arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm) -- ++(0,-1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

@Max: please feel free to revert the changes that follow:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{rusia}{RGB}{85 85 57}
\definecolor{brightcerulean}{rgb}{0.11, 0.67, 0.84}
\definecolor{brandeisblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.44, 1.0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% fix wrong implementation of xy canvas
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro\yangle{30}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    y={({0.5*cos(\yangle)*1cm},{0.5*sin(\yangle)*1cm})},
    x={(1cm,0cm)},
    z={(0cm,1cm)}
]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (5,4,0);
\coordinate (D) at (0,0,2.5);
\coordinate (E) at (0,4,1.3);
\coordinate (F) at (5,4,1.75);
\draw[very thin,canvas is xy plane at z=0,darkgray!40] (0,0) grid (5,4);
\draw[ultra thin,gray] (D)--(A)--(B)--(C)--(F);

\begin{scope}[decoration={zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm}]
\shade  (A)--(D) decorate {-- (E)}--(B)--cycle ;
\shade  (B)--(E) decorate {-- (F)}--(C)--cycle ;
\end{scope}

\draw[thick,opacity=0.3] (0.2,1.5,0) -- ++ (0.5,0,0) coordinate (rod end);

\shade[top color=white,bottom color=brandeisblue,shading angle=45] (0.2,1,0.2) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) -- ++(0,1,0) arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm) -- ++(0,-1,0) arc (\yangle-90:\yangle+90:0.2cm);
\shade[ball color=Cerulean!50, shading angle=225] (0.2,1,0.2) circle (0.2cm);

\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (D)--(E);
\path[decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 1.74cm, amplitude =1mm},decorate] (E)--(F);

\draw[very thin,brandeisblue!70] (0.2,1,0.2) circle (0.2cm) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) -- ++(0,1,0) arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm) -- ++(0,-1,0);

\begin{scope}
\clip (0.2,1,0.2) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) -- ++(0,1,0) arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm) -- ++(0,-1,0) arc (\yangle-90:\yangle+90:0.2cm);
\draw[thick,opacity=0.3,line cap=round] (0.2,1.5,0.2) ++({0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)})  arc (\yangle+90:\yangle-90:0.2cm);
\end{scope}
\path (0.2,1,0.2) ++({-0.2*cos(\yangle+90)},0.5,{0.2*sin(\yangle+90)}) --
(rod end) coordinate[pos=-1] (rod start);
\draw[thick] (rod start) -- (rod end);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Max Sorry, I haven't drawn the wood, it should be.

Comment: @kalakay If you also want the wooden stick and the accompanying shadows drawn, you might want to switch to more realistic alternatives such as `asymptote`. It might prove difficult to do that with Ti*k*z.

Comment: @Max Please feel free to revert the edit I made. (I am not 100% it is easy to convince asymptote to draw a highly non-orthographic projection, but you are right that if this can be done, the shadows and so on will be more straightforward than in Ti*k*Z.)

Comment: @marmot Thanks for the edit, looks very nice!