# Difference between \usetikzlibrary{3d} and \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

Tags: tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

Is there any difference between those two tikz libraries for 3D plots?

I have found the documentation for `tikz-3dplot` on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot?lang=en), but nothing for the \usetikzlibrary{3d}.

Might be related to [Documentation of the tikz 3d library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75945/documentation-of-the-tikz-3d-library)

Comment: There is some documentation, source at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/03aa54d26fe2a1d6130c65240d41262961005d86/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-library-3d.tex.

Comment: Starting on page 564 of the tikz manual you can find the documentation for the `3d tikzlibrary`.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the 3d coordinates are now an integral part of tikz, and I don't even ned to load the library to support coordinates like (y,z,x).
Puha, that manual is just soooo big and so hard to find anything. Thanks @leandriis for pointing this out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tikz-3dplot` (without an `s` in the end) loads the `3d` library (and also `calc`) automatically. So it has all the features of the `3d` library simply because it loads it. In addition, it has commands that allow one to install a 3d view like `\tdplotsetmaincoords` and `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords`, and means to do real 3d plots (hence the name). Other ways of installing a 3d view in Ti*k*Z are to use the `perspective` library (the key is called `3d view`) or `pgfplots` (the key is `view` and similar keys). The conventions for the view angles differ, unfortunately, between these packages/libraries.

The main purpose of the `3d` library is to switch to coordinate planes (such as `canvas is xy plane at z=<z>`), which is of course something that makes most sense once you have established a proper 3d view.

3d coordinates are supported by Ti*k*Z without further ado. However, the predefined view is not orthographic. You can rectify this by carefully choosing `x`, `y` and `z`, but it is much more convenient to use the above-mentioned tools for that.

This example is supposed to illustrate some of these statements.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cube/.style={insert path={
  (-1,-1,-1) edge ++(0,0,2) -- (1,-1,-1) edge ++(0,0,2)
  -- (1,1,-1) edge ++(0,0,2) -- (-1,1,-1) edge ++(0,0,2) -- cycle
  (-1,-1,1) -- (1,-1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (-1,1,1) -- cycle
  }}]
 \def\LabelPlanes{  
  \node[canvas is xy plane at z=1,transform shape]{xy plane};
  \node[canvas is xz plane at y=1,transform shape]{xz plane};
  \node[canvas is yz plane at x=1,transform shape]{yz plane};} 
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A]
  \draw[cube];
  \LabelPlanes
 \end{scope}
 \path (A.south) node[below]{plain Ti\emph{k}Z};
 %
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}% theta,phi     
 \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,tdplot_main_coords,local bounding box=B]
  \draw[cube];
  \LabelPlanes
 \end{scope}
 \path (B.south) node[below]{\texttt{tikz-3dplot}};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm,3d view={110}{20},% phi,90-theta of tikz-3dplot
    local bounding box=C]
  \draw[cube];
  \LabelPlanes
 \end{scope}
 \path (C.south) node[below]{\texttt{perspective}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The left-most picture is not an orthographic projection of a cube, but shows that you can use 3d coordinates in Ti*k*Z right away. The next pictures show the cube in the same projection in `tikz-3dplot` and perspective, and one can see that the conventions for the latitude angle (usually called theta) differ. The example also illustrates one, perhaps the main, application of the `3d` library: project something on a coordinate plane. This works with nodes, as illustrated, but of course also with drawings and external graphics.

Note that the main purpose of the perspective library is not to install a 3d view. Rather, as its name suggests, it allows one to install a 3 point perspective view, yet this discussion is beyond the scope of this answer.