# Drawing a parallelopiped in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I need to draw a parallelopiped like this in TikZ:

[image]

I want to draw in 3D using views and not in 2D.

Comment: Since your question is not clear enough to me (what do you *exactly* mean by *draw in 3D*? Do you want to be able to change perspective of this sole cuboid?), I strongly recommend to learn from [this very comprehensive tutorial](https://latex.net/tikz-3dplot/). And you can also find useful informations from [this post on TeX-SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534487/difference-between-usetikzlibrary3d-and-usepackagetikz-3dplot).

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512415/are-there-simple-ways-to-draw-parallelepipeds-in-tikz)

Answer (score 6):

TikZ is internally 2D, so you can only draw **one** 2D projection on the screen plane of the oblique cuboid; some packages like `tikz3d-plot`, `3dtool` or the library `perspective` may be used.

In case of real 3D Asymptote, you can copy the following code to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ click Run, then use the computer mouse to rotate the output figure. You can guess the meaning of the numbers in the 3-dim transform `ty` for slanting along y-axis; the last column in the matrix is always `$(0,0,0,1)^T$`.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(4cm);
import three;

// slanting along y-axis
transform3 ty={
{ 1, 0,  0, 0},
{ 0, 1, .4, 0},
{ 0, 0,  1, 0},
{ 0, 0,  0, 1}
};

draw(ty*unitcube,yellow+opacity(.5));
draw(ty*unitbox,purple+opacity(1));
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[fill=cyan] (0,0)--(4,0)--(5,3)--(1,3)--(0,0);
        \draw[fill=green] (5,3)--(1,3)--(2,4)--(6,4)--(5,3);
        \draw[fill=yellow] (4,0)--(5,3)--(6,4)--(5,1)--(4,0);       
        \draw[dashed] (2,4)--(1,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(1,1);
        \draw[dashed] (1,1)--(5,1);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'd use the [xyz coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.2) then. And then we're not far from the [TPP](https://tikz.dev/library-perspective) library and its CS.